# Indexing jsonb for numeric comparison of fields

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I've defined a simple table with

```
create table resources (id serial primary key, fields jsonb);
```

And it contains data with keys (drawn from a large set) and values between 1 and 100, like:

```
   id   |    fields                                                                                                 
--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 | {"tex": 23, "blair": 46, "cubic": 50, "raider": 57, "retard": 53, "hoariest": 78, "suturing": 25, "apostolic": 22, "unloosing": 37, "flagellated": 85}
      2 | {"egoist": 75, "poshest": 0, "annually": 19, "baptists": 29, "bicepses": 10, "eugenics": 9, "idolizes": 8, "spengler": 60, "scuppering": 13, "cliffhangers": 37}
      3 | {"entails": 27, "hideout": 22, "horsing": 98, "abortions": 88, "microsoft": 37, "spectrums": 26, "dilettante": 52, "ringmaster": 84, "floweriness": 72, "vivekananda": 24}
      4 | {"wraps": 6, "polled": 68, "coccyges": 63, "internes": 93, "unburden": 61, "aggregate": 76, "cavernous": 98, "stylizing": 65, "vamoosing": 35, "unoriginal": 40}
      5 | {"villon": 95, "monthly": 68, "puccini": 30, "samsung": 81, "branched": 33, "congeals": 6, "shriller": 47, "terracing": 27, "patriarchal": 86, "compassionately": 94}
```

I'd like to search for entries whose value (associated with a particular key) is greater than some benchmark value. I can accomplish this, for example via:

```
with exploded as (
    select id, (jsonb_each_text(fields)).*
    from resources)
select distinct id
    from exploded
    where key='polled' and value::integer>50;
```

... but of course this does not use an index, and it resorts to a table scan. I wonder if there is:

1. A more efficient way to query for resources with "polled" >50
2. A way to build indexes that will support this kind of query

Answer (score 7):

You haven't specified what kind of `INDEX` you are expecting to be used and you haven't provided a definition of it.

The typical `INDEX` for a `jsonb` field would be a [GIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) one, but in your specific case you need to actually **compare** some values contained in the `polled` key.

*Maybe* a specific `INDEX` (though not a `GIN` one!) with an [expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-expressional.html) could be of some use, but I doubt it and it could get quite cumbersome since you would need at least a double type cast to obtain an integer value and a custom `IMMUTABLE` function to actually perform the type casts in your `CREATE INDEX` statement.

Before taking a complicated route which would solve just some specific cases (what if you'd need another comparison with a different `fields` key?), you could try to optimize your current query, taking advantage of PostgreSQL 9.4 new [LATERAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) capabilities and `jsonb` processing functions.
The result is a query that should run up to 8 times faster than your current one:

```
SELECT r.id 
    FROM resources AS r,
    LATERAL jsonb_to_record(r.fields) AS l(polled integer) 
    WHERE l.polled > 50;
```

---

**EDIT :**

I did a quick test to put in practice the idea in my comment to use a `GIN INDEX` to restrict the number of rows before actually comparing the values, and it turned out you can really make some use of a `GIN INDEX` even in that situation.

The `INDEX` must be created with the default operator class `jsonb_ops` *(**not** the lighter and more performing `jsonb_path_ops`)* :

```
CREATE INDEX ON resources USING GIN (fields);
```

Now you can take advantage of the index simply including an exist `?` test in the query:

```
SELECT r.id
    FROM resources AS r,
    LATERAL jsonb_to_record(r.fields) AS l(polled integer) 
    WHERE r.fields ? 'polled' AND l.polled > 50;
```

The query now performs about **3 times faster** *(which is about 20 times faster than the first CTE version)*. I've tested with up to 1M rows and the performance gain is always the same.

Keep in mind that, as expected, the number of rows plays an important role: with less than 1K rows the index is quite useless and the query planner probably will not use it.

Also don't forget the `jsonb_ops` index can become huge compared to the actual data. With a data sample like yours, ranging from 1K to 1M rows, the index itself is about **170%** bigger than the actual data in the table, check it yourself:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('resources')) AS whole_table, 
       pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('resources')) AS data_only, 
       pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('resources_fields_idx')) AS gin_index_only;
```

Just to give you an idea, with about 300K rows like your data sample, the table is about 250MB, consisting of 90MB of data and 160MB of index!
Personally, I would stick *(and I actually do)* with a simple `LATERAL JOIN` without an index.

Comment: Re: "What kind of `INDEX` I am expecting": I don't know -- that's the crux of my question :-) So I can't really give "a definition of it".

Apologies if I was unclear: I'm looking for an indexing solution that would support this kind of query for *any* field key (not just `polled`). There are a large number of field keys, and they're unpredictable, such that a solution requiring one-index-per-field-key wouldn't work. I like the `LATERAL` join approach, but it still doesn't address the issue of indexing (i.e. the query you wrote requires a table scan, as far as I can understand).

Comment: So I guess you are out of luck here. You simply can't have an index on *any key* and expect to use it with any operator, including arithmetical ones. You could use a [GIN INDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) in a query where you first check the existence of a given `key` and then, for all the rows containing it, compare the actual value.But I'm not sure that would perform any better than the `LATERAL` join, and it would greatly depend on the number of rows. For a very similar case I went with `LATERAL`, I believe that's the currently faster option.

Comment: I've updated my answer, using the `INDEX` and with some considerations about it.